# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory` when I start my web application.

As you can see in the image below, I have `tomcat-juli.jar` in my classpath for the Tomcat server configuration but it's still not working.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: put it into webcontent/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: What operating system you are using

Comment: @Ghayel Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @JohannesJander did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had to add the `tomcat-juli.jar` to the classpath in the run configuration for the actual Java Application. All the answers I saw on the internet just pointed out that the Tomcat server needs this in his classpath (see my question).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the tomcat-juli.jar in a path (the lib directory) that Tomcat use to load classes. If your Tomcat does not find it you can copy the jar in the lib directory of the JRE that you are using.

Comment: The image I provided shows `tomcat-juli.jar` in the directory `/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/` where it actually resides. Shouldn't it work that way?

Answer (score 0):

Try export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/tomcat-juli.jar. 
You can find more information [Here](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tomcat)

I am seeing you are adding path as `/usr/share/tomcat8/bin` instead of `/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/` Please check this also