# ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory

Tags: java, tomcat

I dont know what to provide to solve this problem but here's the log.

Im running this on apache tomcat 10.0.6

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.(LifecycleBase.java:39)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
> ... 1 more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361687/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-juli-logging-logfactory)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour] and read [ask].  You are expected to do some research before posting a new question.

Comment: @Nic3500 thank you but that doesnt answer my question. Honestly, I tried many solutions that appeared, it did not work for that's why I resorted in asking here.

Comment: How do you start Tomcat?

Comment: @FanBoySooWP You should include in your question what you have tried so we can propose solutions that will help you.